# Run c# visual studio project in windows, created in ubuntu

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ubuntu, .net-core

I've got a problem with Visual Studio console application created in Ubuntu 15.04. When I try to run c# program in Visual Studio in Windows 10 I get an error "visual project does not contail any commands in project.json and cannot be start". How to fix that? 
I have only json file but I don't have any sln and csproj.

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself.

Comment: please include your project.json also.

Comment: Sounds like you have a pre-release version of the .NET Core tooling installed. Make sure you have the latest .NET Core SDK and Visual Studio updates: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution: create new, empty console app and paste content (.cs) files from linux repo to it. Build and compile.
Remember to resolve conflicts which may occur (libs used in linux environment  may be problematic in windows).